# Setting provisioning parameters on the bitnami/kafka helm chart

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

We want to use Kafka provisioning parameters.
The parameter which we are struggling with is "provisioning.topics".
There exists this documentation describing it a bit: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/kafka#kafka-provisioning-parameters

Given the documentation we want to use the following command:

```
helm install kafka bitnami/kafka --set externalAccess.enabled=true --set externalAccess.service.loadBalancerIPs[0]='' --set provisioning.enabled=true --set provisioning.topics[0]="123test"
```

Which gives us the error:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: kafka/templates/kafka-provisioning.yaml:76:43: executing "kafka/templates/kafka-provisioning.yaml" at <$topic.name>: can't evaluate field name in type interface {}
```

We couldn't find any examples as to how to use the `--set provisioning.topics[0]="123test"`, all approaches remain without success.

Any hints would be much appreciated.

--
Regards

Comment: Ideally, you create topics after the cluster is running, not during installation. You could also use Strimzi Kafka Operator to define a Topic as a k8s custom resource

Comment: It would be ideally for us to create them when we install Kafka. : )

Comment: Hi, this seems to be something to report in github.com/bitnami/charts. If it is failing when rendering the templates it looks like an issue in the chart to me

Comment: Created one there.

Comment: Operators are more configurable than Helm, though, so that's my recommendation. It'll still get you to your goal of running Kafka

Answer (score 0):

There is some documentation [in the `values.yaml` file](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/d2ecf9aac0270925f18a32340655a1c352a6275c/bitnami/kafka/values.yaml#L1435), though it is too light for my liking also:

```
  ## @param provisioning.topics Kafka topics to provision
  ## - name: topic-name
  ##   partitions: 1
  ##   replicationFactor: 1
  ##   ## https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs
  ##   config:
  ##     max.message.bytes: 64000
  ##     flush.messages: 1
  ##
```

You can also have a look at [the template file](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/d2ecf9aac0270925f18a32340655a1c352a6275c/bitnami/kafka/templates/kafka-provisioning.yaml) to see how [it is used for the relevant section](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/d2ecf9aac0270925f18a32340655a1c352a6275c/bitnami/kafka/templates/kafka-provisioning.yaml#L137):

```
{{- range $topic := .Values.provisioning.topics }}
  "/opt/bitnami/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh \
      --create \
      --if-not-exists \
      --bootstrap-server ${KAFKA_SERVICE} \
      --replication-factor {{ $topic.replicationFactor | default $.Values.provisioning.replicationFactor }} \
      --partitions {{ $topic.partitions | default $.Values.provisioning.numPartitions }} \
      {{- range $name, $value := $topic.config }}
      --config {{ $name }}={{ $value }} \
      {{- end }}
      --command-config ${CLIENT_CONF} \
      --topic {{ $topic.name }}"
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Little bit outdated, but I bet someone will hit this page.
With Tiltfile:

```
    helm_resource(
    name='kafka',
    chart='bitnami/kafka',
    flags=[
    '--set=provisioning.enabled=true',
    '--set=provisioning.topics[0].name=test,provisioning.topics[0].partitions=1',
    ],
    labels=['bus']
)
```